# SQL Left Join taking 12 min

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables that I am trying to compare.  The tables are the same structure and should be exactly the same with 60,000 entries each.  However some entries are different and I would like to find the issues.  I am currently trying to do a left join on each of them and show the results.  I am currently getting results but it takes 12 min for each Query.

Table 1 (temp_entries)

```
ID | File
```

Table 2 (temp_dir_scan)

```
ID | File
```

Query 1 (12.25 min)

```
SELECT A.ID, A.File 
  FROM temp_entries A 
  LEFT JOIN temp_dir_scan B ON A.File = B.File 
 WHERE B.File is Null
```

Query 2 (12.26 min)

```
SELECT A.File 
  FROM temp_dir_scan A 
  LEFT JOIN temp_entries B ON A.File = B.File 
 WHERE B.File is Null
```

Query 3 (11.54 Min)

```
SELECT A.ID, A.File 
  FROM temp_entries A 
 Where A.File not in (select B.File from temp_dir_scan B)
```

What is the matter? Or what can I do to speed this up?  What is a reasonable time to complete this in?

Here are examples of the results.

```
1|test.txt
2|test2.txt
45|temp.jpg
```

Comment: please show the result of EXPLAIN SELECT A.ID, A.File FROM temp_entries A LEFT JOIN temp_dir_scan B ON A.File = B.File WHERE B.File is Null
 , and also EXPLAIN  SELECT A.File FROM temp_dir_scan A LEFT JOIN temp_entries B ON A.File = B.File WHERE B.File is Null , so we can see what happend

Comment: You can create an index on feld `File`

Comment: You may try the not in clause: SELECT A.ID, A.File FROM temp_entries A.Filenot in (select B.File from temp_dir_scan B)

Comment: `Null` is undefined and you are trying to do equate it so most likely is throwing it off and hence slows it down.   If you want to compare the 2 tables and find differences in values for `File` column, another way would be to do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and then in the outer query check if `A.File IS NULL OR B.File IS NULL`

Comment: Indexes, Indexes, use EXPLAIN and avoid cartesian products.

Comment: @Sari Rahal - sorry, i mean put EXPLAIN before your query and execute it. and post the result

Comment: @vmachan could you show an example?

Comment: @Sari Rahal - posted an answer as unable to format in comments

Comment: @vmachan it results in an error "Duplicate column name 'ID'

Comment: execute your `SELECT ...` as `EXPLAIN SELECT...` and share the output you get.

Comment: And how do i tell them apart?

Comment: @Sari Rahal - updated to address the duplicate column error.. hope this helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you could try and do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, an example using your tables shown below (MySQL does not have FULL joins so using UNION to emulate this)

**UPDATED**: To remove duplicate column errors

```
SELECT C.A_ID
     , C.A_File 
     , C.B_ID
     , C.B_File
  FROM (
    SELECT A.ID AS A_ID
          ,A.File AS A_File
          ,B.ID AS B_ID
          ,B.File AS B_File
      FROM temp_entries A
      LEFT 
      JOIN temp_dir_scan B
        ON A.File = B.File
     UNION
    SELECT A.ID AS A_ID
          ,A.File AS A_File
          ,B.ID AS B_ID
          ,B.File AS B_File
      FROM temp_entries A
     RIGHT 
      JOIN temp_dir_scan B
        ON A.File = B.File
       ) C
WHERE C.A_File IS NULL 
   OR C.B_File IS NULL
```

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql) gives more information about doing `FULL OUTER JOINS` in MySQL.

Hope this helps

NOTE: Unsure how much of a performance gain is seen compared to your original query(ies).

Comment: This wish a mix of indexing the File column worked perfectly.  Thank you!